# Retrieving a sorted array of dictionary keys based on object value

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an `NSMutableDictionary` that contains information like so:

```
Key="Blue" Value=@[@1, @33]
Key="Red" Value=@[@5, @33]
Key="Green" Value=@[@4, @33]
Key="Pink" Value=@[@2, @33]
Key="Purple" Value=@[@3, @33]
```

I'd like to get an array of keys back, sorted in order by the first object in the Value array.  So in my example above, I'd like an array with this ordering:

> Blue, Pink, Purple, Green, Red

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: I've tried using SortDescriptors but that isn't getting me anywhere

Comment: You should always post your own attempt(s) in the question, to make people know you have done an effort to research the question beforehand. Otherwise it smells of homework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [keysSortedByValueUsingComparator](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:)

```
NSDictionary *dict =
@{
  @"Blue": @[ @1, @33 ],
  @"Red": @[ @5, @33 ],
  @"Green": @[ @4, @33 ],
  @"Pink": @[ @2, @33 ],
  @"Purple": @[ @3, @33 ]
  };

NSArray *sorted = [dict keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [[obj1 firstObject] compare:[obj2 firstObject]];
}];

NSLog(@"%@", sorted);
```

Output:

```
2014-10-28 23:37:34.267 Temp[62789:3909211] (
    Blue,
    Pink,
    Purple,
    Green,
    Red
)
```

Comment: No, the use of `>` was wrong and would only work if the object pointers just happened to be in the same order as the actual number values. And this is likely true since the `NSNumber` objects for the values 0-12 are constants.